# opencv not working on Python3

Tags: software-installation, python-3, opencv

I  have installed OpenCv on my Raspberry pi Model 3B.
It is working for python 2.7 but not for python 3
The **error** im getting is:

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import cv2
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/**init**.py", line 3, in <                            module>
> > >           from .cv2 import *
> > >       ImportError: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-arm-l                              inux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_fetch_add_8

**EDIT :**
I tried using cmake: according to https://answers.opencv.org/question/215735/make-error-__atomic_fetch_add_8-on-raspberrypi4/

I am getting the followin error:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \

> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
>   -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=${HOME}/opencv_contrib-${OPENCV_VERSION}/m                                     odules \
>   -D ENABLE_VFPV3=ON \
>   -D ENABLE_NEON=ON \
>   -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
>   -D WITH_TBB=OFF
>   CMake Warning:
>     No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
>     same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
>     become a fatal error in future CMake releases.

CMake Error: The source directory "/home/pi" does not appear to contain C                                     MakeLists.txt.

**EDIT :**

installed opencv-python=4.1.0.25
and it worked  using pip install opencv-python=4.1.0.25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Updated 12 Oct 2020)*

There's a known issue with some old opencv wheels on piwheels. You need to preload python3 with:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1 python3
```

But newer versions are now available: https://www.piwheels.org/project/opencv-python/

Comment: tried it i am getting bash command not found error